# Proving theorem for finding maxima and minima for 2-variable functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

My Calculus textbook uses Taylor's formula to proof the theorem relating the value of the hessian, the second derivative with respect to x and the point being a maximum or a minimum of the function. My professor stated that he would need to use Taylor in order to prove the theorem, but I believe I did it without needing it. My question is: is this proof correct? If it isn't, can it be, after some corrections or improvements ?

Theorem: If $f(x,y): Dom[f] \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a class C$^2$ function, $(x_0,y_0)$ is an $f$ critical point interior to $Dom[f]$ with $H(x_0, y_0) > 0$ and $f''_{xx} (x_0, y_0) > 0$, then $(x_0, y_0)$ is a local minimum point of $f$.

Proof: $$ g(t) \equiv f(x_0 + ht, y_0 + kt) $$
        $$ \vec{v} \equiv (h, k) $$
        $$ g^{(r)}_{\vec{v}}(t) = \sum_{p=0}^{r} \binom{r}{p} \frac{\partial ^r f}{\partial x^{r-p}  \partial y^p}(x, y) h^{r-p} k^p $$
        $$ g''_{\vec{v}}(0) = \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2} (x_0,y_0) \cdot h^2 + 2 \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} (x_0,y_0) \cdot hk + \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y^2} (x_0,y_0) \cdot k^2 $$
        $$ a \equiv \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2} (x_0, y_0) \qquad b \equiv \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} (x_0, y_0) \qquad c \equiv \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y^2} (x_0, y_0) $$
        $$ Q(h,k) \equiv a\cdot h^2 + 2b \cdot hk + c \cdot k^2 = g''_{\vec{v}} (0) $$
        $$ f''_{xx} (x_0, y_0) = a > 0, H(x_0, y_0) > 0 \Rightarrow Q(h,k) = g''_{\vec{v}} (0) > 0 \ \forall \vec{v} = (h, k) \neq \vec{0} $$

It had already been proven that, given a quadratic of the form $Q(h,k) = a\cdot h^2 + 2b \cdot hk + c \cdot k^2$, one may wirte it as $Q(h,k) = a \left( h + \frac{b}{a} k \right)^2 - \frac{ac - b^2}{a}k^2$ and, if $a>0$ and $ac - b^2 > 0$, then $Q(h,k) > 0  \ \forall (h,k) \neq (0,0)$. In this specific case, the Hessian plays the role of $ac - b^2$ and $\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ plays the role of $a$.